# Ideal of minors for $\phi$ is determined by the image of $\phi$

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Bruns and Herzog p.21

> Let $U$ be an $m \times n$ matrix over $R$ where $m, n \geq 0$. For $t=1, \cdots, \min(m,n)$ we then denote by $I_t(U)$ the ideal generated by the $t$-minors of $U$.

Let $\phi: F \rightarrow G$ be a homomorphism of finite free $R$-modules, where $R$ is commutative. Then it is "easy to show that $I_t(\phi)$ is already determined by the submodule Im $\phi$". I don't see how that's true...

Comment: This holds for any $t \in \mathbb{N}$. Hint: $I_t\left(\phi\right)$ is the span of all $h\left(\left(\wedge^t \phi\right)\left(u\right)\right)$, where $h$ ranges over all $R$-linear maps $\wedge^t G \to R$, and where $u$ ranges over all elements of $\wedge^t F$. It remains to see that the set of all $\left(\wedge^t \phi\right)\left(u\right)$ with $u \in \wedge^t F$ depends only on $\operatorname{Im}\phi$. But this set can be described as the image of the ...

Comment: ... map $\left(\operatorname{Im}\phi\right)^{\otimes t} \to G^{\otimes t} \to \wedge^t G$, where the first arrow is induced by the inclusion map $\operatorname{Im}\phi \to G$, and the second arrow is the canonical projection used to define $\wedge^t G$.